# Verify: If $X \times Y$ is finite, then $X$ and $Y$ are finite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

As a counterexample, consider $X = \mathbb{Z}_+$ and $Y = \varnothing.$ $X$ is clearly infinite, and so not both $X$ and $Y$ are finite. Moreover, $X \times Y = \varnothing$ since $Y$ is empty. Thus, $X \times Y$ is finite.
Therefore this is not generally true. Is my proof rigorous enough? Also, I was thinking if there are cases this can be true.

Comment: In general if $X$ and $Y$ are non-empty this is true, assuming the axiom of choice. In fact I believe this is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: You tagged the question "topology". Do you allow the empty set as a topological space? (I can't recall what the convention is, or if there is some disagreement, as with semigroups). If these are not meant to be topological spaces, then please tag your question correctly.

Comment: @Fishbane I don't think AC is involved. If $X$ and $Y$ are nonempty, let $y_0\in Y$. The map $X\to X\times Y$ sending $x$ to $(x,y_0)$ embeds $X$ into a finite set. That subsets of finite sets are finite does not require AC, I think (perhaps not does if you are using Dedekind finite or something like that?)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, sorry, you are right. I was thinking of infinite products

Comment: Your reasoning and conclusion are correct, your counterexample does the job.